# Can't display more than two menu buttons - holo_light_theme

Tags: android, menu, menuitem

I have a menu  but I only get the two out of three menu items displayed in the action bar. I think it's a matter of space, because if I reorder the items at the xml file, I always get the first two items. How can I get more space  to display all three items?

Part of the activity with the menu items:

```
   ....... @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_catagory, menu);
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                break;      
            case R.id.action_favorite:
                Intent i = new Intent(MapActivity.this, FavouriteListActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);   
                break;      
            case R.id.action_catagory:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MapActivity.this, NearByPlacesActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);  
                break;          
            case R.id.action_check:
                Intent u = new Intent(MapActivity.this, ChackinListActivity.class);
                startActivity(u);   
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }

           return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }.........
```

The .xml file with the menu items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item android:id="@+id/action_check" 
        android:icon="@drawable/check" 
        android:title="@string/action_check" 
        yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_favorite" 
        android:icon="@drawable/favourite" 
        android:title="@string/action_favorite"
         yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_catagory"
        android:icon="@drawable/search"
        android:title="@string/action_catagory"
        yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have missed something here, but wouldn't `yourapp:showAsAction="always"` instead of `yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"`in each of your MenuItem solve this?